# Java & SQL onto corporate server

Tags: java, sql, swing, netbeans, applet

I am writing a program which will sit on a corporate server. It will be accessed by staff using Microsoft and Apple laptops. The program shows information from an SQL database depending on the information requested by the staff. I am using SQL EXPRESS and Netbeans IDE 7.4. I have created a test project in netbeans and successfully connected to the database. I don't really know much about servers so my questions are as follows:

1. How will we put the java program and SQL db on the corporate server?
2. Shall I use java application or applets for the java side (I
   currently just did a test project using JFrames)?
3. If you suggest I do applets, will this be ONLY visible by the staff or could anyone else get access via the internet? (we need it to be for 5 staff members only - company has 12 staff)